# Unable to get data through requests from API in Python

Tags: python-3.x, api

I am new to api and a little confused with what is the cause of the issue. I am accessing api through 2 ways:

a. I open the api url through the chrome website and it displays the result.

b. When I try to access the same api through requests.get(url), I get 403 error.

Do you know if this is possible that there is security issue involved when you access through python?

I tried same code for other api links as well and they work perfectly fine except this link.

PS: I can't share the links.

Comment: Check cookies and User-Agent header. Actually you need to copy all the headers used by browser, but these are most common places to check

Comment: thanks, it worked by adding user agent header

Comment: Post this as an answer with details

Comment: done, do you know why it is necessary to add header user agent?

Comment: This is a simple protection against bots

Comment: okie thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed by adding headers:

```
requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
```